# foreach in Makefile doesn't display a list of files

Tags: linux, foreach, makefile

all:

Why doesn't the following 3-line Makefile show any files at all;
even though I know there are files in $(SOURCE) directory.
There is no syntax errors.

Thank you in advance

---

```
SOURCE := src

CFILES := $(foreach, dir, $(SOURCE) , $(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.c)))

all:    
        echo "$(CFILES)"
```

---

Phi Luu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have a comma after the `foreach` which you don't want.

Second, you have to be very careful with whitespace in makefiles.  Any *trailing* whitespace in a makefile, including in a function, is preserved as part of the word.

Rewrite this as:

```
CFILES := $(foreach dir,$(SOURCE),$(notdir $(wildcard $(dir)/*.c)))
```

Another option would be:

```
CFILES := $(wildcard $(addsuffix /*.c,$(SOURCE)))
```

Comment: Thank you, that extra comma is the culprit. Also thanks for the warning about extra embedded whitespace.